# how to split an array or a list according to the values

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list of numbers as shown below. this is actually a list of indexes from a different array that i am working with.. i am trying to group some data according to a condition.. i manage to obtain this array. but i need separate the series of indexes.

```
array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,23,24,25,26,55,56,57,58]
```

how can i separate this like sub lists as below
expected results:

```
result = [[0,1,2,3,4,5],[9,10,11,12],[23,24,25,26],[55,56,57,58]]
```

Comment: Did you drop the `0` or is this a typo?

Comment: sorry.. its a typo